# How can I pass data from service/thread class to the main activity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-intent

I have created variable in the main activity called `"sum"` and in the Thread of the service I created loop that increase variable by 1 like this:

```
public void run() {
    for(int i=0;i<50000000;i++) {
        num++;
    }
```

Now I want that every time that the variable `"num"` is increased by 1 , it will update the value of `"sum"` to the value of `"num"`.

but I don't really know how to do it .

**I want that it will be a live update and not after the thread will be end or the service  will be destroyed.**

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make the activity bind to the service and define the interface for it.
But does it have to be a service? Maybe a AsyncTask can be an easier solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will accomplish that by broadcasting an intent in you service thread, and registering a receiver for that type of intent in your main thread. For that you will need three components:

- The intent, with added Extras if you need additional data sent from the service to your main thread
- Broadcast receiver, a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`, and executes it's `OnReceive` method when an intent is broadcasted
- An intent filter, basically the thing that links a Intent to a Receiver. You register a receiver using a filter type.

I could retype the code, but on this link there are explanations on how to use that. You are interested in the last three slides:

http://www.slideshare.net/CodeAndroid/android-intent-intent-filter-broadcast-receivers

Also, check this out:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html